# Core dump when main function returns

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, coredump

I have a class that's supposed to write to a gml file defined below. The class has one method that does the writing. If I call the function, I get a core dump when the main function returns. I can create objects of the class with no problem, it only happens when the write function is called. The function also returns with no error and the rest of the program runs.

GML Writer:

```
class GMLWriter {
public:
    void write(List<User*> usr, const char* filename);
};

void GMLWriter::write(List<User*> usr, const char* filename)
{
    cout << "Filename: " << filename << endl;
    ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open(filename);
    if (!outfile.is_open())
        cout << "Couldn't open the file..." << endl;
    outfile << "graph [\n";

    // Write user data
    for (int n = 0; n < usr.size(); n++) {
        cout << "Writing node..." << endl;
        outfile << "node [\n";
        outfile << "id " << usr[n]->getID() << "\n";
        outfile << "name \"" << usr[n]->getName() << "\"\n";
        outfile << "age " << usr[n]->getAge() << "\n";
        outfile << "zip " << usr[n]->getZip() << "\n";
        outfile << "]\n";
    }

    // Write associations
    for (int n = 0; n < usr.size(); n++) {
        List<int> tList = usr[n]->getFriends();
        cout << "Writing edge..." << endl;
        //List<int> tempL = usr[n]->getFriends();
        for (int i = 0; i < tList.size(); i++) {
            outfile << "edge [\n";
            outfile << "source " << usr[n]->getID() << "\n";
            outfile << "target " << tList[i] << "\n";
            outfile << "]\n";
        }
    }

    outfile << "]"; // end graph
    cout << "End function" << endl;
    outfile.close();
}
```

User simply contains the variables to write to the file, and those methods work fine.

I've spent hours with this in a debugger and haven't been able to find the problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please include source from your calling line?

Comment: Can you show us the output? Do you see "Writing Node.. " or "Writing Edge"..?

Comment: Please post the *destructor* for class `List<T>`. Then, change the parameter to your writer to take a const-reference instead of a copy. Finally, follow [**The Rule Of Three**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)). I'm thinking `List<T>::~List()` deletes the list contents, which means whatever list you're passing to this by value will delete those pointers on the way out, and since you likely provided no copy-constructor for your `List<T>` class, the default was used. Thus back in `main()` we now have a `List<User*>` full of deleted pointers. Leave main, and boom.

Comment: I see all the expected outputs (ie "Writing node..." and "Writing Edge..."). I also see "End function."

Comment: There is no destructor to post. There's nothing in the class to deallocate. I call the function with the following code: GMLWriter writer; writer.write(theUsers,argv[2]); where "theUsers" is a list of User objects.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the core dump: http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_38.html